# Relational Database, Superkey, Candidate in my example

Tags: sql, relational-database

I know there are a lot of examples for superkeys and candidates, but I'm don't know, hot this is in my example. So would apreciate your opinion to it.

I got this table:

```
licenceNumber# | carSerialNumber | manufactor | model | year
kr-ad 102 | 112345 | ford | mustang | 1972
ab-cd 291 | 54331 | volkswagen | polo | 1990
```

Here's my opinions

**Superkeys:**

```
licenceNumber
licenceNumber, carSerialNumber
licenceNumber, carSerialNumber, manufactor
licenceNumber, carSerialNumber, manufactor, model
licenceNumber, carSerialNumber, manufactor, model, year
carSerialNumber
carSerialNumber, manufactor
carSerialNumber, manufactor, model
carSerialNumber, manufactor, model, year
carSerialNumber, manufactor, model, year, licenceNumber
```

So there are **10** superkeys

and **2** candidates (`licenceNumber`, `carSerialNumber`) because there are **unique** and I could pick one of these to be the **primary key**

Am I right with that?

Thanks ahead

Comment: The 5th and 10th in your list are the same combination. And you are missing many others, like `(licenceNumber, model, year)`

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right. No. 5 and 10 are the same in a different order. I get it.

So is there a method to write down, how many superkeys exits? 
It seems to be hard work, to write down every possible superkey.

This was a exam question.